# Rest web service with security

Tags: security, rest, oauth, jersey, token

I have wrote an web service that returns the scheduler from a given student. I must now secure the web service, because the data are confidential.

It's a rest web service using jersey.

My idea is to exchange token, like OAuth or similar. I searched on the web and can't found a library that implements oAuth with helpful examples.

Can anyone provide me examples that uses a OAuth library for securing an web service ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Jersey OAuth lab we presented at this year's JavaOne: http://java.net/projects/jersey/downloads/download/oauth_lab.zip

Note the instructions on how to set up the environment to be able to run the lab is in an appendix at the end of the lab guide.